# How to do a person search and return back those lines in a select group of spreadsheets in a SharePoint document library

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a need for a user to type in a name of a user on a SharePoint page and have it only look for all occurrences of this name in a series of spreadsheets stored in a single document library.  This should return a series of lines where this person's name found.

A few things.
 - The names used in the spreadsheets are not exact matches to those in
   SharePoint and in fact will be first last instead of last, First as
   in SharePoint.  Maybe only accepting last names?
 - These spreadsheets do have a property called Deliverable set to RACI.
 - The spreadsheet lines look like this: Sponsor,DHS,Krista Willing,A,A,A,R,A,A,A

I have started the design and my first web part is a list filter allowing the user to pick a name.  I then want to take the last name of what is selected and do a search in a document library for all the RACI (excel documents with RACI as a property) and display the results.  This last part I'm still trying to figure out.

Comment: I get that your response will assist me in customizing the output of which I do not have access to the master pages, but I don't see the mechanism that will get the contents from within each spreadsheet.  My understanding is that CSWP will return the list of documents and you template will allow me to format this list in a way that is "pretty", but I need to do a search within the documents that are returned.  Ideally, I'd love to keep the format of the spreadsheets.  I see that excel services could work if I could get a slicer or a filter working in addition to processing all RACI files.

Answer (score -1):

We can implement this using customizing the display template and content search webpart, please refer the below link how to customize the display template :

**Content By Search Web Part**

Content By Search Web Part(CSWP) was introduced in SharePoint 2013. CSWP has power to display dynamic content from SharePoint search index, based on dynamic search queries. It uses Display Templates for styling and formatting search results on the page. A big advantage of using CSWP over CQWP is, there are no scope boundaries for getting data across sites. However freshness of results depends on the latest crawl on content.

**Display Templates**

Display Templates are used with CSWP to format/style search result generated by CSWP search query. Display Templates control which managed property is shown in the search results and how they appear in the Web Part. Each Display Template has two files: an HTML version of the Display Template that you can edit in your HTML editor, and a .js file that is for SharePoint use and should never be modified. CSWP uses combination of two Display Templates, Control Templates and Item Templates to render results.

Control Template provides HTML to structure the overall layout for how you want to present the search results.For example, the Control Template might provide the HTML for a heading, beginning and end of a list. The Control Template is rendered only once in the Web Part.

Item Template provides HTML that determines how each item in the result set is displayed. For example, the Item Display Template might provide the HTML for a list item that contains a picture, three lines of text that are mapped to different managed properties associated with the item. The Item Display Template is rendered one time for each item in the result set. So, if the result set contains ten items, the Item Display Template creates its section of HTML ten times.

https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.technet.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/00/92/84/8233.figure2.jpg

There will be two display templates

- Header or control Display template
- Item Display template

We need to customize the item display template. Process is - download the default item display template from display template gallery, rename the file name, do the customization, upload back the customized display template, publish it, go to content search web part, from web part setting select the newly updated item display template.

**Sample item display template code :**

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Picture URL'{Picture URL}:'PublishingImage;PictureURL;PictureThumbnailURL','Link URL'{Link URL}:'Path','Line 1'{Line 1}:'Title','Line 2'{Line 2}:'Description','Line 3'{Line 3}:'','SecondaryFileExtension','ContentTypeId', 'FileExtension'{FileExtension}:'FileExtension
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_quick_reads/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24593358)

Comment: @Ru Chern Chong - updated the answer... actually for this answer is descriptive, one should know what is display template, item template etc... and need to how to customize.